# How to perform a hardware reset of a galaxy tab S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

My tablet is stuck at a screen (S Voice) and otherwise completely irresponsive.

I tried to press the power key for some time, hoping for a hardware reset (like the one found on PCs). I also tried the `Power-Volume-Home` combo - no response.

**Is there a hardware way to reset a tablet ?** (I see a tiny hole on the edge, right of the Home button but it is really tiny)

- I do not want to perform a factory reset or "hard reset" as shown on numerous pages (using `Power-Home-Volume`). This requires the tablet to be powered down
- I can wait for the power to drain and hope the tablet will restart but I would prefer to perform a reset first

Comment: Holding the Power button for a full 30 seconds should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up waiting for the power to completely dry up and it restarted.